# Data Table column resize going wrong

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables, jquery-plugins, resize

I am using **DataTable** plug-in to display data in table format and **jQuery-UI** plugin to resize a table column via Drag and Drop.

**landing.html**

```
        <div class="card computedresultrow" style="display: none; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table id="computeddatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr id="canheader">
                            <th>CAN ID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="canbody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**custom.js**

`$('#computeddatatable').DataTable();`

```
function resizeCols(){
    $('table th').resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            $(this).width(ui.size.width);
        }
    });
}
```

I am able to drag and drop columns, but **it is going wrong**, like if I drag to the right, the column divider goes to the left, it is not accurate.

Please advice.

Thanks,